# libreoffice calc If statement with result cell and second sheet source of true variable

Tags: if-statement, libreoffice, calc

I've got a calculated cell that has "TRUE" or "FALSE" as a result. I want another cell to post linking statement from Sheet2 and keep on getting back the false vale no matter what I try here.

```
=IF(H2="TRUE",'2'.$B$2,'2'.$B$4)
```

So the setup I read should go like this IF(Test, Then Value, Otherwise Value)
Any help on what I'm missing here would be much appreciated.

Just in case it helps I have the formula in H2 as `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(H1,B2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your formula uses a string comparison for the test - but `TRUE != "TRUE"`. Did you try `=IF(H2,'2'.$B$2,'2'.$B$4)` or `=IF(H2=TRUE(),'2'.$B$2,'2'.$B$4)`?